# random sample results for access sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a column called names, it is meant for there to be several rows with the same name. I need to find a way to make a query to give as result a 4% random sample of the rows with every name using Access SQL syntax. For example, if there are 100 rows of each name in the table, for it to return 4 random rows for each name on that column. Does that make sense?

I'm not very experienced on Access SQL and SQL in general, yet. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This material might be helpful

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153747/en-us